# How to influence a prospective employer after interviews are over?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, applications

So the process went like this:

- I applied to the advertisement of the company
- After a few weeks I had a response and was invited to an interview two days later
- I did the interview and I believe was quite good
- Two days after they invited me to a second interview, what I found positive
- I did the second interview two days later and the interview run well I believe.
- After that they did not give me any news for around two weeks
- I texted them to get some feedback. I also found they have a slack community so I joined it and texted them there.
- After few days they replied me that they are still making interviews for other candidates and they will make their final decision next week.

My question is: Is there anything I can do at this stage to influence their opinion about me?

For instance, since I joined their slack community well after our interview, I think this might make me more visible and maybe it shows my interest in the company. I am sure I could do other stuff but I do not want to be annoying or look too desperate or unpolite. I think that would be a wrong step, if I look annoying like contacting them too much.

Comment: Is the slack community officially open to the public? It would seem unusual if the community consisted only of employees and a single prospective candidate. Do others outside the company contribute to it?

Comment: It is like public. Anyone could join. So I did, out of curiosity to find out my interviewers were there. So I could potentially send them messages. But I am afraid it will annoy them or something. Since they already told me they are intervieweing and will give news next week.

Comment: Congrats on the 3rd interview. Perhaps close this question?

Comment: No. Interview is over now but the question holds: Should I do something else to influence them?

Answer (score 10):

You've done everything you can do - i.e. you've demonstrated that you're still keen. Any more beyond this would definitely cross into

> annoying or look too desperated or unpolite

In my opinion.

Comment: Still, I am wondering. Because I am really interested in this position: Is there anything I could do to influence them without being unpolite? I feel so terrible just sitting back and waiting, and cannot stop thiking if there is still anything on my hands I could do to influence them.

Comment: @Worker Nope.. while I understand (and sympathize) with the terrible feeling of waiting, you've done all you can and anything else is just going to be counterproductive.

Comment: @Worker I have to agree with motosubatsu that you've already exhausted all available options. Any further attempts to "push" yourself will most likely result in you being rejected on the spot because of this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything I can do at this stage to influence their opinion
>   about me?

You can send them a letter via snail-mail thanking them for their time, telling them how impressed you were with the company, how excited you are about the possibility of working for them, an how you look forward to hearing their decision next week.

Address it to the hiring manager (or whoever you think is the primary decision maker.)

To be honest, it's unlikely to matter very much. But it won't hurt and every little bit could help.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there anything I can do at this stage to influence their opinion about me?

I can't see much else you could do.  As Joe stated above a polite letter via snail-mail would be a reminder.

As you stated - anything else would be (as you've stated) *be annoying or look too desperate or un-polite.*   Your instincts are correct - don't do these things.  If you get the job then great; if not the accept this any move on to a different job.